# How to import mysql modules in Python?

Tags: python, mysql

As you are aware, I am a complete noob on this.

I am trying to use this reusable class to connect to mysql Python Connection with MySQL

But whenever i try to run the python I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "src/connect.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Mysql import Mysql
  File "/home/ubuntu/myproject/src/Mysql.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql
ImportError: No module named mysql
```

I tried installing MySQL-Python, and result shown on pip freeze says that the modules installed...

```
easy_install MySQL-python
Searching for MySQL-python
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.5
Adding MySQL-python 1.2.5 to easy-install.pth file

Using /home/ubuntu/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for MySQL-python
Finished processing dependencies for MySQL-python
pip freeze
    Cheetah==2.4.4
    Landscape-Client==14.01
    MySQL-python==1.2.3
    PAM==0.4.2
    PyYAML==3.10
    Twisted-Core==13.2.0
    Twisted-Names==13.2.0
    Twisted-Web==13.2.0
    apt-xapian-index==0.45
    argparse==1.2.1
    chardet==2.0.1
    cloud-init==0.7.5
    configobj==4.7.2
    jsonpatch==1.3
    jsonpointer==1.0
    oauth==1.0.1
    prettytable==0.7.2
    pyOpenSSL==0.13
    pycurl==7.19.3
    pyserial==2.6
    python-apt==0.9.3.5
    python-debian==0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2
    requests==2.2.1
    six==1.5.2
    ssh-import-id==3.21
    urllib3==1.7.1
    virtualenv==1.11.6
    wsgiref==0.1.2
    zope.interface==4.0.5
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide details on that reusable class, (maybe post the file via paste bin and then provide a  link to it or something).

I think it should be `import MySQLdb`  rather than just `import mysql`

If your class relies on this module being named as `mysql` then instead of changing all the entries in the entire code of the class you could also just do `import MySQLdb as mysql`

Hope this helps.